# Bootstrap carousel indicator position is currently overlapping carousel content

Tags: javascript, css, html, carousel

I'm making use of bootstrap's carousel features on my portfolio, this includes a few indicators below the content to enable easy browsing through the content(some text based testimonials).

The indicators are supposed to be positioned directly below the text, unfortunately it seems that the indicators sometimes overlap the text, this seems to be worse on mobile layouts but can be seen on desktop resolution 1920x1080 when clicking the penultimate carousel indicator.

Ideally I would have the carousel indicators always appearing below the text. Can somebody advise on how I might force them to respect the height of the carousel item?

An example of the issue can be seen here: http://www.robertmegone.com/#testimonials

Additionally, I'm hoping it's possible to smooth the transition when the carousel item container grows and shrinks. Currently when the length of the text changes it jumps to the different heights. I'd like it to ease. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Links to external sites can be useful at first. But if they become deprecated in time. The question no longer becomes any use to any other user on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just give the element with the class "carousel" a padding-bottom of e.g. 60px (and you can remove the padding-top from the "carousel-indicators" element).
The indicator element has "position: absolute" and "bottom: 0" which will place it always in the padding of the carousel element.

Regarding the second question: You could use javascript to iterate over each slide, get the biggest hight and set it as hight for every slide. But be careful, as its responisve, you have to do that on every resize event of the browser.